# Chef git :sync action not pulling new code - am I getting it wrong?

Tags: git, deployment, chef-infra

So, I have the following `default.rb` file:

```rb
directory '/path/to/dir' do
  action :create
end

git '/path/to/dir' do
  action :checkout
  repository 'https://github.com/mkkekkonen/TS-Math'
end

git '/path/to/dir' do
  action :sync
  repository 'https://github.com/mkkekkonen/TS-Math'
end
```

But my newest changes do not show in the directory. I thought the `:sync` action would do the trick. What am I doing wrong? I'm totally new to Chef.

Answer (score 0):

I indeed was getting it wrong. I thought the default branch name ("deploy") was the branch that was checked out from the remote repository. In fact, the checked out branch is the master branch of the GitHub repository.

The newest changes showed on my server after I merged them into the master branch in the remote repository.